# Formatting errorindicator

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I need to format the errrorindicator depending on the textfields stylename. I couldn't find any css rule which takes the v-errorindicator style in dependence of a stylename for the textfield e. g.

```
.my-stylename-for-textfield .v-errorindicator {
    style: xxx;
}
```

Does someone know a posibility?

Best regards
Bernhard

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the errorindicator depending on your textfield style, you can style it depending on your overall theme name.

What I mean is that, Vaadin will generate a CSS file that's specific to your theme name, wihch you specify in you main UI:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {
//....
```

And generates a CSS that looks like the following:

```
.mytheme .v-textfield { 
text-align: left;
 }
```

So you need to style your errorindicator specifying the name of your theme and the CSS hierarchy, which in your case is under the textfield:

```
.mytheme .v-textfield .v-errorindicator {
color: blue;
}
```

If you need more info on how to use Vaadin themes, check out the [Theme chapter](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html) in the Vaadin book.